# When I try to install ubuntu my computer freezes then shuts down

Tags: system-installation

It's a really old computer that I had lying around and windows got corrupted so I tried installing Ubuntu but it freezes and shuts down after 10 minutes. I manage to start booting off my USB but when I click install Ubuntu it freezes and shuts down.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need atleast 1GB of RAM to install from Ubuntu Live CD.

Since you have mentioned that the your computer is an old one, I guess your computer may not have 1 GB of RAM.

In that case, try the Ubuntu Alternate Installer [32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-i386.iso) or [64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64.iso)

Comment: This site (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) says that 512 MB will do for the Ubuntu Desktop Edition. Please provide a link for the 1 GB requirement.

Comment: The last time I tried to install Ubuntu on one of my old comps, I faced a similar problem. I had read somewhere in the Ubuntu site that for installing you require a minimum of 1GB RAM, but for running Ubuntu 512MB may be enough. I am not able to find the link, I will post it as soon as I find it.